# flowbite design is different after splitting the components

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3, flowbite

I copied exactly this code exact code from a flowbite component:

https://flowbite.com/docs/components/sidebar/#sidebar-with-navbar

However I wanted to make things in components like this:

```
import Navbar from '../../../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Sidebar from '../../../components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import Content from '../../../components/Content/Content';

export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Sidebar />
      <Content />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately I got this weird and different design.
Note: The code from flowbite works like it is.

[image]

Comment: can you make jsfiddle or codesanbox for this problem ?